# Json Root Name not coming in Camel Swagger Rest Service

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, swagger

I am trying to create rest service using apache camel swagger component.

Now i have this camel context as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <!-- a bean for user services -->
  <bean id="personService" class="www.tempuri.person.PersonService"/>


  <camelContext id="myCamel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="auto" contextPath="myService/rest" port="8080">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <!-- defines the rest services using the context-path /Equipment -->
    <rest path="/getPerson/persons" consumes="application/json,application/xml" produces="application/json,application/xml">
      <description>Person rest service</description>
       <post uri="/search" type="www.tempuri.person.model.GetPerson" 
                outType="www.tempuri.person.model.GetPerson">
        <description>Get Person(s)</description>
        <param name="body" type="body" description="Get Person(s)" required="true"/>            
        <responseMessage code="400" message="Bad Request" />
        <responseMessage code="200" message="Person Data" />
        <responseMessage code="401" message="Unauthorized" />
        <to uri="bean:personService?method=getPersons"/>
      </post>
    </rest>
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

And below is my model class GetPerson:

```
package www.tempuri.person.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@ApiModel(description = "Represents Persons")
@XmlRootElement(name="getPerson")
@JsonRootName(value = "getPerson")
public class GetPerson {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Application Area of GetPerson", required = true)
    private ApplicationArea applicationArea;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Data Area of GetPerson", required = true)
    private DataArea dataArea;

    /**
     * @return the dataArea
     */
    public DataArea getDataArea() {
        return dataArea;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataArea the dataArea to set
     */
    public void setDataArea(DataArea dataArea) {
        this.dataArea = dataArea;
    }

    public ApplicationArea getApplicationArea() {
        return applicationArea;
    }

    public void setApplicationArea(ApplicationArea applicationArea) {
        this.applicationArea = applicationArea;
    }
}
```

Now in case of application xml it is working good and the request structure has a root element as getPerson, but in case of JSON Request it doesn't show the root element getPerson. I know that there is something called **WRAP_ROOT_VALUE** which can be used to enable the root name in case of json. But the problem is i don't know how to do it using camel-config.xml.

How can i set the WRAP_ROOT_VALUE through my camel-config.xml or is there some other way. Thanks in advance..